# Using functions to write input() into a file and read the file - NameError

Tags: python, file

I'm trying to create a program that takes user input and saves it into a text file, each time adding to the document and not overwriting previous entries.

When trying to run the program I get the following error:

> files.write(file, a, b, c, d)
>   NameError: name 'a' is not defined

I've defined a in `def how()`. Why is the variable 'a' not accessible for `def write()`?

```
def how():

    a = input("--")
    b = input("---")
    c = input("---- ")
    d = input("----- ")


def open_file():
    global file
    file = open("diary.txt","r")
        for line in file:
        print(line) 
    file.close()

def write():
    files = open("diary.txt","w")
    files.write(file, a, b, c, d)
    file.close()

how()
open_file()
write()
```

Comment: What do you mean you can't get it to work? You need to give a clearer explanation of the problem

Comment: So it works, or not?

Comment: You're not supposed to edit your question into something completely different as that will invalidate the current answers.

Answer (score 1):

your variables `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` are *local* to function `how()` and `write()` and therefore `write()` doesn't  know what to write.

Return the values in `how()`:

```
def how():
    d = '' # default value
    print (time.strftime("%I:%M:%S"))
    print (time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))
    a = input("How are you today?: ")
    b = input("What things happened today?: ")
    c = input("What was the main happening of the day? Was it good or bad?: ")
    if "good" in c:
        print("Good? That's great.")
    else:
        d = input("I'm sorry it wasn't good. How can I help?: ")
    return a, b, c, d
```

Get these values when you call `how()`:

```
a, b, c, d = how()
```

And use them in `write()`:

```
def write(a, b, c, d):
    files = open("diary.txt","w")
    files.write(file, a, b, c, d)
    file.close()
```

And pass the arguments when you call `write`:

```
write(a, b, c, d)
```

Comment: I tried your solution and got this error - TypeError: write() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'a', 'b', 'c', and 'd'

Comment: @JohnH Check my answer. It fix this problem.

Comment: Still not working - NameError: name 'a' is not defined

Comment: @JohnH my bad. I did not indent the `return` properly.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear from your question, but i'm guessing `diary.txt` does not have the content you expect it to have.
Have a look at the [docs for open()](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#open), it says this:

> 'w'    open for writing, truncating the file first

So your file is getting truncated every time you try to write to it.
But the docs also say this:

> 'a'    open for writing, appending to the end of the file if it exists

Therefore, try opening the file with:

```
open('diary.txt', 'wa')
```

Answer (score 0):

You `how()` functions needs to return the `a, b, c, d` values:

```
def how():

    print (time.strftime("%I:%M:%S"))
    print (time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))
    a = input("How are you today?: ")
    b = input("What things happened today?: ")
    c = input("What was the main happening of the day? Was it good or bad?: ")
    if "good" in c:
        print("Good? That's great.")
    else:
        d = input("I'm sorry it wasn't good. How can I help?: ")
    return a,b,c,d
```

Get them:

```
a,b,c,d  = how()
```

And when you `write` them, send them:

```
write(a,b,c,d)
```

And write the file. Be careful with this, you have an error in your code.

```
def write(a,b,c,d):
    file = open("diary.txt","wa")
    file.write(a)
    file.write(b)
    file.write(c)
    file.write(d)
    file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

To add each time and not overwrite you need to open file in 'a' (append) mode:

```
open(file, 'a')
```

Also, now you are closing *file* two times, but not closing *files* anywhere. It is good habit to open files like this:

```
with open(file, 'a') as diary:
    diary.write(b)
    diary.write(c)
```

This way the file will be automatically closed after you leave the *with* block, even if there were an exception raised in *with* block.

Answer (score -1):

This works!

```
import time

a = ""
b = ""
c = ""
d = ""
prevFile = ""

def how():
    print (time.strftime("%I:%M:%S"))
    print (time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))
    global a
    global b
    global c
    global d
    a = input("How are you today?: ")
    b = input("What things happened today?: ")
    c = input("What was the main happening of the day? Was it good or bad?: ")
    if "good" in c:
        print("Good? That's great.")
    else:
        d = input("I'm sorry it wasn't good. How can I help?: ")

def check():
    file = open("diary.txt","w")
    file.write("---")
    file.close()

def open_file():
    global prevFile
    file = open("diary.txt","r")
    for line in file:
        prevFile += line
    file.close()

def writeFile():
    files = open("diary.txt","w")
    files.write(prevFile)
    files.write(a + "\n")
    files.write(b + "\n")
    files.write(c + "\n")
    files.write(d + "\n\n")
    files.close()

how()
# check()
open_file()
writeFile()
```

Comment: It does thanks. I'll look into the code and why it's working here.